# C# how to delete and update data without database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to delete the input data from datagridview. This can hide it after a action it appear again.

I tried to use this

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in table.SelectedCells)
    if(oneCell.Selected)
        table.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);


private void displayData()
    {
        table.DataSource = null;

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data.Columns.Add("Serial Number");
        data.Columns.Add("Car Type");
        data.Columns.Add("Bin Location");
        data.Columns.Add("Park Duration");
        data.Columns.Add("Park Fees");

        for (int i = 0; i < carInfoSize; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(carInfo[i, 0]) && !carInfo[i, 0].Equals("0"))
            {
                data.Rows.Add(carInfo[i, 0], carInfo[i, 1], carInfo[i, 2], carInfo[i, 3], carInfo[i, 4]);
            }
        }

        table.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use foreach loop for deletion of items within collection because It will generate an error.

Comment: Is it web application or Windows?  Can you share the code of how are you loading data in the grid view?  And on what action you try to delete data?

Comment: its a window form